# Is This Receptacle Up To Code?

Tags: electrical, bathroom, receptacle, code-compliance, usa

I recently added this receptacle to my bathroom because I am putting a vanity here that has a built-in power bar and previously the only receptacle in the bathroom was the GFCI outlet at the top of the image. I put the new receptacle low to the ground because I need to be able to fit the plug for the vanity underneath the vanity's feet, or else the vanity wouldn't be able to be pushed right up into the corner. The new receptacle is GFCI protected by the aforementioned GFCI receptacle, and while it is only a 15 amp receptacle, it is wired to the GFCI outlet with 12/2 wire which leads back to a 20 amp breaker.

In all my research, I didn't find any code requirements for minimum outlet height or orientation, but my friend saw my work and said that flooding could pose a hazard and now I am questioning myself.

I am in the United States where NEC is the applicable code.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, that's really low, but seriously, if water ever gets that high in your bathroom, you are having problems! And if it does, the GFCI should trip and protect you. I don't think there is any specific code guidance on this, is it even going to be inspected?

Comment: @GlenYates Thanks for your input. No, I'm not getting this inspected (not required in my locality), but I would like to remain code-compliant for my own sake/ability to sleep at night.

Comment: Orientation definitely shouldn't matter - there isn't even agreement on ground pin bottom or top. Agree with Glen Yates as far as the water issue.

Comment: One code that you might need to know, is that outlet needs to be accessible.  Can't be behind the wall of the vanity, but possible only needing to get on your hands and knees is okay, if you can reach it.

Comment: @crip659 Good point. The vanity is a "drop-in" vanity, which is like a piece of furniture. It's not attached to the walls. Even then, the outlet is accessible (by design) with the vanity in place (i.e. I can put the vanity in place and then plug the power bar in to the outlet)

Comment: those pipes look like they're part of the walls, dose the vanity attach to them?, also an outlet is not the sort of thing that it's a good idea to hit with a mop.

Comment: @Jasen Yes those pipes are for hooking up a sink on the vanity. The outlet will be covered by the vanity, so I don't think a mop getting near it is a concern

Comment: it has to be 3 feet above the ground

Comment: @Ruskes citation needed. Maybe you are referring to the required counter receptacle? This is an additional receptacle.

Answer (score 3):

Some states require compliance with NEC 406.12 for TR receptacles.  I can't tell from the photo which type is installed there.  If you've replaced the GFCI, then NEC 406.4(D)(5) also applies where enforced.

The only orientation requirement I can think of is that it can't be on the floor facing up if it's under the sink.

Overall, it doesn't look any worse than the average dishwasher outlet.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Both the GFCI and additional outlet below are TR receptacles